# Filter out SU questions where votes are negative

Tags: support, questions

I'm getting SU questions with "https://superuser.com/questions?sort=newest&pagesize=50&page=1"
Is there a way to filter out 'silly' questions which were voted down from url above?

Comment: isn't exactly the same (since it hides positive scored questions) but you don't get negative scored questions with this http://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a0

Comment: You could use http://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a0%2b but it doesn't sort the same, as new answers are also considered for the sort order, not just questions.

Comment: @DanielBeck I found a -1 question with that url :(

Comment: It appears there is not way to accomplish this using the search, because `score:0` is special. [This](http://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a1%20is%3aquestion) shows all questions with a score of *1 or higher*, but `score:0 is:question` will just show all questions with an exact score of *0*.

Comment: @DanielBeck There is, but the syntax is [not quite what you'd expect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188786/159624). You need to specify it like `score:<min>..<max>`

Comment: [There we go](http://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a0..10000%20is%3aquestion), thanks @slhck. Of course, the search doesn't update when there's new questions, so I'd still prefer the regular page and just ignore negative score questions if I didn't want to see them. Or maybe even write a userscript for it?

Comment: @slhck you can actually use `..0` for a `<=0`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify things (and b/c I hate answers in comments) you can filter your searches by using SU Search FU.  Here's the [specific query](https://superuser.com/search?q=score:..0%20is:question) you'll need:

```
is:question score:..0
```

However you should look over the help page for [searching](https://superuser.com/help/searching).